# Using castle windsor in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, castle-windsor, castle, global-asax

Guys, I need to use castle windsor for a sharepoint project. I have created a new class library project (MyIOCProject) which has a class (CastleConfiguration) to do my configurations. The class inherits from Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHttpApplication

I have placed the MyIOCProject.dll in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/my app version/bin

Then in "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/my app version" I have changed global.asax from

**<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint"%><%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHttpApplication" %>**

to

**<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint"%><%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="MyIOCProject.CastleConfiguration" %>**

After an IISReset I get the following error: Could not load type 'MyIOCProject.CastleConfiguration'.

Can someone help please.

Comment: Don't you need to specify assembly too when specifying type name?

Comment: Thanks, that was the reason I was getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, see comments to the question. (adding this so that answer can be accepted and question doesn't show up as having no answers.)